# How to design at the situation that we need generalized compare-and-swap semantic in Datomic?

Tags: clojure, datomic, compare-and-swap

My problem is like this:

I need to use Datomic to model:

1. The user can propose request. Initially, the request is in open status.
2. The admin can approve/reject/modify the user request.

The request schema is like:

```
:req/status     ;; cardinality one. It can be: open, modified, approved, rejected
:req/things     ;; cardinality many. [thing-id ...]
```

The admin sees the user requests from a web application UI. There are three options for admin: approve, reject, modify. If a request is approved or rejected, then this request is no longer alive. It will disappear from admin UI. However, if a request is modified, it can still be approved, be rejected, or be modified again. When the request is modified, only the `req/things` can be modified. There may be multiple admins operating at the same time on the same request in this system.

The state diagram of request status is:

```
 open -> modified 
 modified -> modified 
 {modified, open} -> approved (done)
 {modified, open} -> rejected (done)
```

Consider a situation:
Two admins A and B process on the same request and they do not sense each other. They push the button at the same time. One admin A approves the request and another admin B modifies the request. The request was originally modified before, so it is at the status `modified` when the  two admins process it.

The correct behavior of the system could be two possibilities: Either operation of admin A is successful or operation of admin B is successful. If operation of admin A is successful first, then the request can not be modified anymore. If the operation of admin B is successful first, then the approval of A should not happen, because the `req/things` is already modified, but the admin A approved different set of `req/things`.

I consider to utilize `db.fn/cas` to guarantee that only one operation of admin A or admin B can succeed. However, `db.fn/cas` does not work on cardinality many.

Currently, I think there are two ways to solve my problem (only one operation can succeed):

- add an additional schema `req/stamp` into req.
  The stamp is initially 0. Every operation will increase it by 1. Then I can use this stamp and `db.fn/cas` to ensure the logically strictness of the operations.
- Install some customized db function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356933/updating-transaction-in-datomic-for-an-attribute-that-has-many-cardinality), which can do CAS on cardinality many to ensure the logically strictness.

I am curious about that which way is more canonical in Datomic to solve this problem, or there is another way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I found that Mongoose since version 3 has a similar design called `versionKey`, which corresponds to the `req/stamp` in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert by all means, but I think introducing the timestamp and comparing it in the transaction is simpler for this use case.